# conditional-buildstep and run-condition jenkins plugins do not get installed through Puppet

Tags: vagrant, puppet, jenkins-plugins

I have written a Puppet script that will install conditional-build and run-condition jenkins plugin. But the plugins do not get installed through the Puppet script.
 The plugins DO get installed manually through the jenkins web interface. 
The manual installation installs .jpi files in the var/lib/jenkins/plugins folder. I tried to remove the .jpi files manually and then do a "Vagrant provision" after which the plugins get installed. This is a very strange behaviour as previously no matter how many times I tried to do a "Vagrant destroy" and "Vagrant reload" and "Vagrant provision"..the plugins never got installed but as soon as I installed the plugins through the jenkins web interface, and then removed the .jpi files from the puppet VM, and then did a "Vagrant provision"..VIOLA the plugins get installed through the puppet script.
  At first I thought that the plugins weren't getting installed thorough the puppet script because the puppet script downloads a .hpi file and a conditional-build/run-condition folder instead of a .jpi file which the jenkins web interface downloads in the /var/lib/jenkins/plugins folder. But I was mistaken as jenkins accepts even the .hpi files after I remove the .jpi file and then do a "Vagrant provision" which then downloads the .hpi file and a plugin-named folder in the jenkins/plugins folder. I wonder if this is a bug because I didn't find a solution for this.

Below is my Puppet Script:-

```
service { iptables: ensure => stopped }

class {'jenkins':
}

jenkins::plugin { "git" :
  version => '1.1.28',
} ->

jenkins::plugin { 'github':
  version => '0.7',
} ->

jenkins::plugin { 'run-condition':
  version => '1.0',
} ->

jenkins::plugin { 'conditional-buildstep':
 version => '1.3.3',
}
```

Comment: if the vagrant command can't control the vagrant instance, you need fix that problem first.

Comment: The vagrant command can control the vagrant instance...the problem is that the plugins do not get installed through the puppet script...As you can see, the git and github plugins have no problem getting installed with the puppet script but conditional-build and run-condition plugins do not get installled.